# How to use mod-rewrite to redirect API calls and web app calls accordingly

Tags: php, apache, routes

I'm building an application with php that offers both an API interface and a web app(HTML) Interface. I have both of these in a directory in my document root:
`/www/sys/api` and `/www/sys/webapp`
in each directory I have a router which is supposed to handle routing

```
/www/sys/api/public/api-index.php

/www/sys/webapp/public/webapp-index.php
```

Now what I want to do is to use a .htaccess file in my `/www/sys/` to route any request in the form of `/www/sys/api/smth/smth/smth` to `/www/sys/api/public/api-index.php?path=smth/smth/smth` and any other request (anything other than `www/sys/api` such as `/www/sys/hello` or just `/www/sys/`) to `/www/sys/webapp/public/webapp-index.php?path=smth`.

Right now I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/(.+)$ api/public/api-index.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api/public/api-index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ webapp/public/webapp-index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

which is working to some extent except that:

1. going to server/sys/api/ sends me to server/sys/webapp/public/webapp-index.php but if I just add one more layer server/sys/api/hhh it works!
2. I'm not getting the full url param if I'm redirected to webapp I always get webapp/public/webapp-index.php and in API I always get public/api-inedx.php

to conclude I need to get this .htaccess to redirect /sys/api/ to /sys/api/api-index.php and get the actual url right. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tweaking I found a solution just posting it here if someone stumbles upon this question
 - renamed the api-index.php and webapp-index.php to just index.php now just going to /sys/api/ or /sys/webapp/ doesn't lead to nowhere!
 - sent the path parameter in a htaccess file in each public directory
so this is the structure:

```
sys
    api
        public
             index.php
             .htaccess [2]
    webapp
        public
             index.php
             .htaccess [3]
    .htaccess [1]
```

[1]:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/(.*) api/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webapp/public/$1 [L]
```

[2] and [3]:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```